# How do I make it so a program can't run if a certain argument doesn't appear in the command line?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a program where I input range arguments at the command line and run a loop until it gets to the end of the range and then write them to a text file

```
./cmdline -b 100 -e 200 -s 4 -f text.txt -m w  // -b = beginning; -e = end; -s = step size; -f = file path; -m = mode
100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 144 148 152 156 160 164 168 172 176 180 184 188 192 196 200
```

How do I make it so the program can't run if one of the range arguments, -b, -e, -s, are missing. Unless an r is written for the mode after the command is written to a text file, then it just reads the text file.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I assumed I could add an if statement and printf to tell the user to input these arguments at specific positions, but I figured that wouldn't work as then the program would have to run with those arguments in those positions. Then I wouldn't be able to read the text file after I write to it, because I wouldn't add -b and -e at that point

Comment: When you're processing the arguments, set a flag for each option. Then check that all the flags are set.

Comment: `if (!(b_set && e_set && s_set)) { // report error and exit }`

Comment: Are you using `getopts()` to process the arguments?

Comment: @Barmar No. I'm using a for loop like this 
```for(int i=1; i<argc; i+=2)
 {
  if(strcmp(argv[i], "-b") == 0)
  {
   unit->start = atoi(argv[i+1]);
  }```
to process them.

Comment: You should use `getopts()`.

Comment: Anyway, just add `b_set = true;` to that `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code below :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   if(argc != numbers_of_arguments) {
      printf("error message"); //a message you want
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < argc;) {
     if(strcmp(argv[i],"your range arguments") != 0) {
        printf("Error give these range arguments");
        return(-1);
     }
     i = i + 2; //cause of position of your range arguments
     if(i == 6) {
        break; // in order not proccess anything else because you reach your range arguments
     }
   }
   return(0);
}
```